# No header on first page of chapter

Tags: latex

I am using the scrpage2 package in my Latex-document to generate headers on each page. Now i get a header which says the name of the current chapter and an unterline.
But i dont want this header on the first page of each chapter, how can i do this?

This is my code:

```
\usepackage[plainheadsepline,headsepline]{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\ihead[\sffamily \upshape \bfseries \headmark]{\sffamily \bfseries \upshape \headmark}

\chead[]{}

\ohead[]{}

\ifoot[]{}

\cfoot[]{}

\ofoot[\sffamily \pagemark]{\sffamily \pagemark}

\automark[]{chapter}

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{1\baselineskip}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `\thispagestyle{empty}` should remove the header specifically from one page.

Comment: Ok this works fine so far but now the pagemark (pagenumber) dissappears on those pages

Comment: If you wish to keep the page number use: `\thispagestyle{plain}` instead

Comment: I've used this command, but then my header does not dissapear

Comment: I could have sworn that worked for me.  Those are all the thoughts I have.  You can ask this on the tex specific version of this site and get better answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com